# How to get the path of an image in the gallery

Tags: android, image, uiimageview, picasso

I want to get the path of an image from the user gallery and show it to the user via Picasso. But I'm having problems with image with extension like '/picasa/150016.png, I mean with image taken from other apps.

Comment: You do not need the path. Just pass the `Uri` to Picasso. It will know what to do with it. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,null);
Cursor cursor =cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
```

But generally it's best to just pass the Uri to Picasso like CommonsWare suggested.

Comment: I tried, but it stills return me a null path for images with uri like this: content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/6015263974142091026